# Magento change grand total & subtotal of an order

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating an order from existing order.

```
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(230);
    $order->setReordered(true);

    $quote = $this->getQuote()->setUpdatedAt(now());
    $quoteCurrency = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load($quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
    $quote->setForcedCurrency($quoteCurrency);
    $quote->save();
```

I am using this "$quote" object to create an order.

Order is creating perfectly. But now I want to update the grand total & sub-total of only newly created order.

I tried below with both $quote & $order object but no success.

```
    $order->setSubtotal(39.99);
    $order->setBaseSubtotal(39.99);

    $order->setShippingAmount(4.99);
    $order->setBaseShippingAmount(4.99);

    $order->setGrandTotal(39.99 + 4.99);
    $order->setBaseGrandTotal(39.99 + 4.99);

    $order->setBaseTaxAmount(0);
    $order->setTaxAmount(0);
```

Any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit Subtotal and GrandTotal in the address obj (Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address).

```
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$customAmount = 4.99;
$address->setSubtotal($address->getSubtotal() + $customAmount);
$address->setBaseSubtotal($address->getBaseSubtotal() + $customAmount);
$quote->collectTotals();
```

Hope it helps